# unable to upload full project to github

Tags: flutter, github, visual-studio-code

I have a github repository where I have uploaded a flutter project,
However with due course of time I have realized one of my files mainly `pubspec.yaml` is not uploaded to github. I have tried various ways to sync my project but wont work.

I dont want to delete the project in github and add create a new one. This is a recurring issue

May I know
what is causing this ?
How can i update my project of vscode including all current files to github without causing any issue ?

Comment: you will need to check .gitignore file, it may be the reason preventing `pubspec.yaml` to be pushed

Comment: here is the gitignore `/.dart_tool
/.flutter-plugins
/.flutter-plugins-dependencies
/.idea
/.metadata
/.packages
/build
/drivers_app.iml
/pubspec.yaml
/README.md
/test`

Comment: SInce `pubspec.yaml` is listed here, it's not uploaded. But I'm not familiar with Flutter, so I can't tell if it *should* be uploaded in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please delete `pubspec.yaml` from .gitignore file, and then try again. More info about .gitignore can be found [here](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/ignoring-files)

Answer (score 1):

Github is currently down (not fully )

If you are trying to push to your repo  you might be experiencing issues

link  : [Github Status](https://www.githubstatus.com/)

Comment: Yes! i realised it .

Comment: its up now, I think they were updating it and it was down for 10 mins. Is your issue resolved now? if it is please mark the answer that helped you as correct so that others can refer the same in future.